# Values from unchecked checkboxes returning as "undefined"

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm sure this has been addressed elsewhere, but I've read 20+ stackoverflow entries trying to find an answer, but all the ones I've read don't address this exactly and when I try to adopt proposed solutions, they just don't work. I'm having issues with unchecked checkboxes in Mad Libs returning a value of `"undefined,"` so that the code below returns the following (if, for example, #check3 is checked and the other two are not):

In the end, their success can be contributed entirely to their undefined, undefined, dedicated [#noun-2 value, which is working just fine].

```
var $end = " In the end, their success can be contributed entirely to their" 
           + $('#check1:checked').val() + ", " 
           + $('#check2:checked').val() + ", " 
           + $('#check3:checked').val() + " " 
           + $('#noun-2').val() + ".";`
```

Any idea of how I can return the values of only checked checkboxes? Do I need to write an if/else to make this happen?

Here it is the html code

```
<div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="adjective-2" value="powerful"> 
        <label for="check1">powerful</label>
    </div>
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="adjective-2" value="honed">
        <label for="check2">honed</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="adjective-2" value="dedicated"> 
        <label for="check3">dedicated</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your selectors are correct and that the element exists when you select it? Mind showing your HTML?

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for providing code examples when asking questions (the html. please..)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've amended to include the HTML.

Comment: When exactly you checking checkboxes/checkbox values (event)? Add some more jQuery, please...

Comment: "I'm having issues with unchecked checkboxes in Mad Libs returning a value of "undefined,"    This is correct. If :checked is used and nothing is checked, it cant find anything so undefinded is returned

Comment: @nevermind, the jQuery I posted is within a form submission event:

`$("form").on("submit", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 makeResults();
}`

And makeResults looks like this:

`function makeResults() {
 var results = document.createElement('section');
 results.innerHTML = '<h1>' + 'A true story:' + '</h1>';
 results.className = 'container results';
 main.appendChild(results);
};`

The problem has been checkboxes returning with "undefined" though it looks like the next comment by Bindrid provides an explanation.

Comment: @Bindrid, that makes sense. I suppose I need to write a conditional to test for checked status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9jex94f/1/)

To get this you can loop through the checked checkboxes, convert the values to an array, and then loop through the array to create a readable list.

## Gathering Values

To gather the values, loop through each checked checkbox and add them to an array.

```
function convertToArray() {
  var array = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).val());
  });
  return array;
}
```

## Making the values readable

You can then reduce the array to a readable human list by calling [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with the following function:

```
function readableList(prev, curr, i, a) {
  let term = curr.toLowerCase();
  let grammer = (a.length === i + 1 && a.length > 1) ? ', and ' : (i > 0 ? ', ' : '');
  return `${prev}${grammer}${term}`;
}
```

## Putting it together

To tie the pieces together you can call an update function like this

```
function onUpdate() {
  var array = convertToArray();
  var list = array.reduce(readableList, '');

  var end = " In the end, their success can be contributed entirely to their " + list + " " + $('#noun-2').val() + ".";
  $('#result').text(end);
}
```

## Full code

```js
$('#updateButton').click(function(){
 onUpdate();
});

function onUpdate() {
  var array = convertToArray();
  var list = array.reduce(readableList, '');
  
  var end = " In the end, their success can be contributed entirely to their " + list + " " + $('#noun-2').val() + ".";
  $('#result').text(end);
}

function convertToArray() {
  var array = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
   array.push($(this).val());
  });
  return array;
}

function readableList(prev, curr, i, a) {
  let term = curr.toLowerCase();
  let grammer = (a.length === i + 1 && a.length > 1) ? ', and ' : (i > 0 ? ', ' : '');
  return `${prev}${grammer}${term}`;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="adjective-2" value="powerful"> 
        <label for="check1">powerful</label>
    </div>
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="adjective-2" value="honed">
        <label for="check2">honed</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="check">
        <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="adjective-2" value="dedicated"> 
        <label for="check3">dedicated</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="text" value="house" id="noun-2">

<button id="updateButton">Update</button>

<h1>Result:</h1>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! This is great and will help me add some understanding to my blossoming education. I look forward to going through line by line to follow your logic. I'm not allowed to upvote yet, but consider this my vote! :-)

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! If this works well for you I think you can still [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/310649) even if you cannot yet make upvotes. Good luck with your education!

Answer (score 0):

**you are trying to get value which is not checked yet that is why you are getting undefined**

*try this to get value*

```
$('#check1').val()
```

*try this is this checkbox is checked or not*

```
$('#check1').is('checked') //this returns true or false
```